# C What is an "arithmetic operator"?

Tags: c, operators

While at least from a hand wave point of view I believe I know what an "arithmetic operator" is, I'm looking for a formal definition.  I've examined the C17 standard document and I can't find such a definition, although it uses the term "arithmetic operator" in several places.

The closest I've been able to find is in the index of C17, where page numbers are provided for additive, bitwise, increment and decrement, multiplicative, shift, and unary under the common heading "arithmetic operators".  I've looked online at various sources and the most common thing I've found only says that binary +, -, *, /, and % are the C arithmetic operators.  Some also throw in ++ and --.

I'm pretty sure I'm simply missing something since I do find the standard quite daunting.  However, I also find the various online sources somewhat dubious since they often seem to differ.

Thanks!

Update: Since some readers objected to my references to both C and C++ in the same posting, I've removed the references to C++ in the modified version above and will do an entirely separate posting for it later if I can first get the issue resolved for C.

Comment: First of all, please pick ***one*** language. There is no such language as "C/C++", there is C and there is a separate and very different language C++. Both have their own separate specifications, with their own syntactic and (more importantly) semantic rules. And the devil is in the details of those semantic rules, what's true for C might be false for C++.

Comment: I don't believe the C++ standard gives a formal definition of the term. The one place it uses the term it refers directly to the definitions of the multiplicative and additive operators (§[expr.mul] and §[expr.add] respectively). What use have you seen of the phrase that convinces you it *should* be formally defined?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude  Okay, please tell me for C first, then for C++.

Comment: @JerryCoffin  Hi Jerry.  I don't have any specific reason to think that it must be formally defined.  However, since the standards do use the term and it seems like a fairly important concept, it also seems like it should be defined formally.  The standards do get down to the level of defining what a digit is and what the "Arithmetic Types" are, so it just seemed logical to me.

Comment: Too broad for multiple languages -Voting to close.

Comment: *I'm pretty sure I'm simply missing something since I do find the standards, especially for C++, quite daunting.* no shame in this. Standards documents aren't intended for most writers of code and often require someone who is a multiclass programmer/lawyer to interpret.

Comment: @BenevolentDeity: As I already said, the C++ standard only uses the phrase in only one place, and in that case it refers directly to the sections on additive and multiplicative operators.

Answer (score 3):

The C standard does not explicitly define the term **arithmetic operator**, though it defines what an **arithmetic operand** is. If you read carefully, nothing in C is defined *by using the term **arithmetic operator***, it exists only as a grouping in the index and in a title of one section. The term **arithmetic operator** by itself does not appear in *any paragraph*.

From [the index](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#Index), we indeed can get a list

> arithmetic operators
>
> - additive, 6.2.6.2, 6.5.6, G.5.2
> - bitwise, 6.2.6.2, 6.5.3.3, 6.5.10, 6.5.11, 6.5.12
> - increment and decrement, 6.5.2.4, 6.5.3.1
> - multiplicative, 6.2.6.2, 6.5.5, G.5.1
> - shift, 6.2.6.2, 6.5.7
> - unary, 6.5.3.3

From this we could formulate that the arithmetic operators are those that require the operands to be *arithmetic operands*, i.e. of an *arithmetic type* (except in special cases such as pointer addition, subtraction), i.e.

- additive `+` and `-`
- bitwise `&`, `|` and `^`
- increment and decrement `++` and `--`
- multiplicative  `*`, `/` and `%`
- shift `<<` and `>>`
- unary `-`, `~` and `+`. It is debatable whether `!` is an arithmetic operator or not, even though it is listed in section 6.5.3.3.

Another notable thing about these operators are that the operands might undergo usual arithmetic conversions.

Answer (score 1):

Arithmatic operators are operators used to perform mathematical operations like addition, substraction, multiplication and division. As simple as that.

ex: a+b = c